# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error when executing code

Tags: c, cygwin

Need help finding out the cause of Segmentation Fault (core dumped) when I execute my code. I have tried to research the cause but found nothing relating to my code.Sorry for the bad code still new to programming

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
char str[1000];
int counta , counte, counti,counto,countu;
int q =0;
    printf("Enter a String: \n");
    scanf("%s" , str);



//if (feof(stdin)) break; //CRTL D TO STOP


    while(1==1 && str[q] != 1000 ) {

    if(str[q] == 'a')
    {
            q++;
            counta++;
    }
    else q++;

    }
    q = 0;

    //while(str[q]

 printf("%d" , counta);


return 0;
```

}

Comment: `str[q]` is never going to be equal to `1000`. Your program goes in an infinite loop and access memory out of bounds.

Comment: You probably meant `q < 1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has a while loop with the condition -

```
while (1==1 && str[q] != 1000)
```

`1==1` is useless because 1 is always going to be equal to 1. the `str[q] != 1000` is also going to be always true because `str[q]` is of type `char` which cannot hold the value `1000`.

Thus your program goes into an infinite loop. It thus ends up accessing memory which is beyond the bound of `str`. And the behavior here is not defined. Mostly in this case your program would crash.

You probably meant the condition to be -

```
while ( q != 1000)
```

This would work and would not cause any undefined behavior, but note that the string ends way before the total length of the array. The string ends on encountering a `'\0'` character. You should use the condition -

```
while ( q < 1000 && str[q] != '\0')
```

Also, be sure not to switch the order of the conditions or your will again end up reading out of bounds memory.